# Watch a folder for new folders, cd into folder (and subfolders) and execute script

Tags: file-comparison

I have a lot of audio files to convert and I like this to happen automatically when moving a folder with files into another folder, where the magic should happen.
It's on a debian system.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And what did you try already ?

Answer (score 3):

Ensure you have inotifywait & ffmpeg installed, set the 3 vars at the start to the correct settings, then try

```bash
#!/bin/bash

watch_dir="WHEREEVER"
convert_from="flac"
convert_to="mp3"

inotifywait -qmr -e 'move,close_write' \
  --include ".${convert_from}" --format '%w%f%0' \
  --no-newline "$watch_dir" |
  while IFS= read -r -d '' file
  do
    ffmpeg -i "$file" -ab 320k \
      -map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3 \
      "${file/%.${convert_from}/.${convert_to}" > "$watch_dir"/log.txt 2>&1
    rm -- "$file"
  done
```

Comment: That looks spectacular, thank you :) Sorry for my ignorance, but I tried to adjust it to what I want it to do and failed. It's a bit more simplistic than your beautiful script. What I like it do is to go into the found folders (and subfolders) and run a wee script I have myself. Is there any change you can enlighten me?

Comment: The `-r` switch means it will look recursively. If you want to call your own script, then just replace the 2 `ffmpeg` & `rm` lines. However I would advise against it as I am not sure you understand how it works.

Comment: @RobertvanWingen: Did you have `inotifywait` and `ffmpeg` installed?

Comment: I do have those installed but I don't want to use ffmpeg, or mp3. I have my own script that converts, renames and adjust the volume. I just need a script that runs that on folders that are moved to the folder that's monitored. Pretty please :)

Comment: In that case, just replace the `ffmpeg` & `rm` lines with the name of your own script & have that script accept just a single argument & act upon it. You will probably need to adjust the `convert_from` var to something meaningful. It's just a simnple regex. Oh, and that script came pretty much out of the man page for `inotifywait`.